# Reference for Deligne-Mumford

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

What is a good reference for someone new to the theory of Deligne-Mumford stacks, other than the original Deligne-Mumford paper itself? The paper itself seems readable with some effort; but the fear is that the reader will miss out on whatever happened in the later years. Is there a good introduction at the graduate level?

Comment: Do you want to learn something about algebraic stacks in general first? DM-stacks are those algebraic stacks for which there is a étale presentation.

Comment: Certainly, some time spent on algebraic stacks is ok. I am completely new to the topic. But the eventual aim is to get to the Deligne-Mumford theory.

Comment: Dear Ashson, Regarding DM stacks (vs. more general algebraic stacks --- what are sometimes called Artin stacks), some arguments are easier in the DM setting, and so if that is where you want to end up, there is nothing wrong with focussing on the DM case.  Even thought is short on details, you could use their original paper as a guide to key facts.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt E, your advice is very valuable. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @somebody with higer reputation: Is it possible to add the tag algebraic-stacks ?

Comment: @Ashon: Dear Ashon, I'm glad the advice is helpful.  Also, I realized there is a possibly confusing typo in my last comment: "thought is short" should read "though it is short".  Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the book of Laumon and Moret-Bailly.

There is of course the stacks project.

There are also Artin's paper on algebraic spaces (his survey on *the implicit function theorem in algebraic geometry* from the Bombay conference, and also his two papers on *algebraization of formal moduli*).  When I was recently trying to learn this material, I found Artin's papers very helpful, even though they are about algebraic spaces rather than stacks proper.

Comment: Dear @Matt: did you omit the word "function" between the words "implicit" and "theorem" in the first line of the third paragraph? (On the other hand, I find interesting the idea that all of algebraic geometry has a single theorem implicit in it...)

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: Dear Asal Beag Dubh, Indeed!  Thanks for pointing this out.  Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the notes by Daniel Halpern-Leistner which can be found at

```
http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~danielhl/moduli_theory_notes.pdf
```